# How to efficiently backup virtual disks?

Tags: virtualbox, backup, vhd, vdi

I have a couple of Unix VMs (FreeBSD and Linux) hosted on a Windows 10 desktop -- using Virtual Box. I'd like to set up regular (daily?) backups for the virtual disks involved.

Because the images are rarely modified, it'd be efficient to use some cleverness -- so as to avoid backing up the entire image every time...

There is little I can do on the host (Windows) side of things -- I'm not a Windows programmer and do not wish to install new Windows software. But on the Unix inside the VMs (especially -- inside FreeBSD), I can do just about anything.

The VMs can see the images on the host (via SMB). They can also access the backup location -- via NFS.

I want the whole VHDs backed up so that, if I have to move the VMs to another host, I don't need to create them again... I'm prepared to deal with minor inconsistencies in case of a future recovery -- `fsck` should be able to fix things...

Is there anything for me already out there, or do I need to create my own?

Comment: I use VMware but the concept is the same (test it). I just copy the machine folder to another machine. That works. I time this for times when machines have been changed in a major way.

Comment: Do the vms use lvm? if so  lvm snapshots written to dosk could be a large part of the solution.